# needs to exclude js/css/jpg etc files from filtering @WebFilter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm filtering every urls i.e. using `@WebFilter("/*")`. User needs to be logged in to view any page, if he's not he's redirected to `/login.do` page.

Now the problem comes up when user goes to `login.do` page because the as the user is not logged in other requests i.e. requests for fetching .js, .css, .jpg, .png etc are also redirected to `login.do` page.

I tried the following code:

```
if(requestedUri.matches(".*[css|jpg|png|gif|js].*")){
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}
```

but in that case, all pages becomes accessible without even being logged in. So, basically I need a way to exclude css, jpg, js files' url from filtering.
Any help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry! that was my silly mistake. the regex was not correct!

that should be `.*(css|jpg|png|gif|js)`

Comment: as an attacker, I would just append ?my_hack=css to my url and bypass your filter :)

Comment: Well, I changed the strategy. but how would you know i'm using regex here? :)

Comment: Assume that an attacker may have access to your source.  Would your system still be secure then?  [Kerckhoff's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle)

Answer (score 1):

if the url like `a/b.jsp` or `a/b.giffs` there will match `.*(css|jpg|png|gif|js)`

so the RegEx should be `.*(\bcss\b|\bjpg\b|\bpng\b|\bgif\b|\bjs\b)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the extension of the request, you should use:

```
.*(css|jpg|png|gif|js)$
```

**Matches** with:

```
hello.htm.jpg
hello.js
hello.ico
```

**Not matches** with:

```
hello
hello.
hello.csv
hello.htm
hello.html
hello.shtml
hello.csv
hello.jpg.csv.htm
```